# CSS gap in mobile navigation menu (only watchable on mobile device)

Tags: css, mobile, navigation

I am working on a responsive navigation and trying to get a responsive design to work.

Now, if you watch the website with a mobile device and you click on the menu button in the left corner the menu drops down, which is working fine. My problem is, there is a gap in between the last part of a sub-menu and the next main menu item ... and for the love of god I just can not find the solution to get that gap lost. :(

You can check the website on your mobile device here: http://bit.ly/1Hwbn94

CSS code:

```
#menue {visibility: visible; z-index: 99999;}
nav ul, nav:active ul {margin: 0; display: none; position: absolute; padding: 0; width: 0; height: 37.5rem; z-index:99998; padding: 0;}
#nav ul, div.menu ul {list-style: none; margin: 6.25rem 0 0 0; padding: 0;}
#nav ul ul {display: block; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; z-index: 99998;}
#nav ul ul a {display: block; padding: 0 50px 0 0; margin: 0; background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .97); color: black; text-decoration: none; text-align: right; font-size: 3.125rem; line-height: 7.5rem;}
nav li {text-align: right; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 800px;}
nav:hover ul {display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#nav a {color: black; display: block; padding: 0 3rem 0 0; text-decoration: none; background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .97); margin: 0; font-size: 3.125rem; line-height: 9rem;}
#nav ul li.current_page_item > a, #nav ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a, #nav ul li.current-menu-item > a, #nav ul li.current-menu-parent > a {background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .99);}
#nav ul.sub-menu {width: 600px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#nav ul.sub-menu li {float: none; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

I do not know, how I did get that gap, but maybe someone different can see the problem/issue. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "#nav ul.sub-menu" rule is inheriting a height of 37.5rem from the "nav ul, nav:active ul" rule, which is bigger than the required height for the sub menu.  Adding "height:auto" to the "#nav ul.sub-menu" class got rid of the gap for me.

Answer (score 1):

> One way to build a horizontal navigation bar is to specify the `<li>` elements as inline, in addition to the "standard" code above:

[W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp) Reccomends using `Display:Inline` for horizontal navigation elements.

and `Display:Block` for vertical navigation, you seem to be using `display:inline-block`, try changing that.

Comment: I changed that one issue, but that did not change anything on the layout. So, there is still that unwanted gap. :(

Comment: change the padding and margin to auto where it has zero, such as: margin:auto; if that doesn't work, put up a jsfiddle of the basic layout and css and i'll take a look

Comment: margin: auto did not fix it. :\ Jsfiddle? The navigation is given dynamically by Wordpress. I can not add that to Jsfiddle, I think.

Comment: ohh okay, can you provide in your question the vital html to your navigation bar